# Extract xml from csv

Tags: xml, bash, csv, awk

I try to extract a whole bunch of xml using awk from a variable that includes csv.

I get the csv from a webservice that spits the following out:

```
2;1;"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<project name=""ETLTasks"" version=""6.0"" modified=""1479827853273"" modifiedBy=""admin"" format=""strict"" olapId=""p0"">
  <headers>
    <header name=""comment"" modified=""1394702840960"" modifiedBy="""">
      <comment><![CDATA[Automated tasks for OLAP Server:
- CubeCopy
- CubeRulesCalc]]></comment>
    </header>
  </headers>
</project>
";
```

I try to use awk to extract the xml. I would like that the double double quotes are replaced by only one double quotes (instead of format=""strict"" => format="strict")

for now I have the following but it does not replace the double doubel quotes as wished:

```
etlDefinitionClean=`echo -n "$etlDefinition" | cut -d";" -f3`
etlDefClean="${etlDefinitionClean%\"}"
etlDefClean="${etlDefClean#\"}"
awk -F "\"*;\"*" '{ gsub(/\"\"/, "\"", $2) } {print $2}' "$etlDefClean"  > "$fileOut"
```

what I want to achieve in the end is the following:

```
<project name="ETLTasks" version="6.0" modified="1479827853273" modifiedBy="admin" format="strict" olapId="p0">
  <headers>
    <header name="comment" modified="1394702840960" modifiedBy="">
      <comment><![CDATA[Automated tasks for OLAP Server:
- CubeCopy
- CubeRulesCalc]]></comment>
    </header>
  </headers>
</project>
```

and put that in a file

Comment: to remove multiple double quotes, just say `tr -s '"' < file`. Also, what exactly do you want to extract from the xml? Instead, better use a tool like `xmlstarlet` to parse such formats.

Comment: added what I try to achieve. I would like to extract the whole xml code, not parts of it

Comment: so you just want to clean the xml part of the string you get by removing the double quotes? Also, what about the `2;1;"` in the beginning? Are they constant?

Comment: yes sir. and 2;1; are constant indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
awk -F '^(2;1;")|(";)' -v RS="" -v dq='""' -v q='"' '{gsub(dq,q,$2); print $2}' csvx.data
```

gives you the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ETLTasks" version="6.0" modified="1479827853273"modifiedBy="admin" format="strict" olapId="p0">
  <headers>
    <header name="comment" modified="1394702840960" modifiedBy="">
      <comment><![CDATA[Automated tasks for OLAP Server:
- CubeCopy
- CubeRulesCalc]]></comment>
    </header>
  </headers>
</project>
```

Using `-v` to create the quotes is just a convenience to avoid lots of escaping. An equivalent command would be:

```
$ awk -F '^(2;1;")|(";)' -v RS="" '{gsub("\"\"", "\"" ,$2); print $2}'
```

`-v RS=""` is a special value for the record separator that tells awk to consider any sequential set of non-empty lines to be a single record.

Comment: thanks a bunch! what if my data comes from a variable and not directly from a file? should I use something like -v variable="$etlDefinitionClean" and so on?

Comment: In that case you would say `echo "$etlDefinitionClean" | awk ...` (and be sure to enclose the variable in quotes to maintain the newlines).